# Using VBA to Search for Text String in a PDF

Tags: vba, pdf

Just wondering if this is possible - I have a folder full of many PDFs that all have the same text string on the first page "Year/Period of Report" followed by "YYYY/MM".  Is there code you can write in VBA that will pull the text following the initial string?  I'm a bit of an amateur at coding, so any help or guidance is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Do the pdfs have OCR information in them?

Comment: I don't think you can use VBA to do that, as VBA work with Microsoft Office product, it cannot read the PDF.  Or you need to convert them into office document first.  Maybe you should choose other language which have related PDF library to achieve that

Comment: @Alex - You absolutely can work with PDFs in VBA - Acrobat supports OLE automation.  There are also other PDF OLE libraries.  VBA works with *COM*, and it can work with COM objects that manipulate PDFs. It isn't a simple Office automation language.

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for your information, forgot about the COM objects.  But if the question just need to work with PDF, should it change to other language?

Comment: @Alex - "Is there code you can write in VBA..."

Comment: @Comintern by OCR information do you simply mean searchable text?  If so, yes, you can perform a simple "find" and locate the "Year/Period of Report" text string I'm trying to reference. While it sounds like it's possible to search and perform functions (locate, copy, etc) on PDFs, I'm a little stumped as to how to write the initial code that will locate the text and then copy the text sting following the reference text

Comment: For example, If I were to code this in VBA and was looking to pull text from another excel workbook my thought process would be - set variable = .find("Year/Period of Report").offset(0,1) and paste the value to my master tab.  Just not sure how to do the same thing with an external program like Adobe.  I know how to code VBA to open the file, just not sure how to search, offset, etc once I'm there...